# Limit Php.ini File Change Per User

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php.ini, suphp

I'm using suPHP with Apache 2 and users is allowed to use their own php.ini

How can I limit changes of global php.ini values to only few modications?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to restrict users to only modifying certain options in php.ini or the number of modifications that can be made in a time period?

Comment: restrict users to only modifying certain options in php.ini. For example, one issue is that default php.ini memory value of 32MB is overwritten to 128MB

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing about any other in built method, I think your best bet would be to write a page that allows users to modify only the values you want them to. This way, not only can you control which settings they can change, but also limit the values to your own preferences. E.g. only allow upload_max_filesize to be between 16M and 25M.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I find a way to allow users to override, there are few lines to comment in the suphp.conf. I will use suhosin to limit all allowed changes.